# Shuffling Javascript array elegantly

Tags: javascript, sorting, shuffle

There are some existing threads about shuffling JS arrays, but they all seem not trivial and not elegant, consisting of many lines of code.

I encountered some blog that suggests the following one line "workaround":

```
yourArray.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
```

If you're not familiar with how sorting algorithms work, I'll explain here briefly that it's always about comparing two values of the array, and then making a decision. The proposed solution "overrides" the default comparison function with another function that for every comparison of two cells, generates a random value (on each comparison it randomly decides which is greater than which).

The problem with it, is that I can't know which sorting algorithm is used by each web browser. For some sorting algorithms, e.g. **BubbleSort**, such a function will probably cause the sorting algorithm to run forever, as it will have **1/2^(length)** probability to have a run without any swap. It seems to also be problematic for **Quicksort**. I think it will finish regularly only if the web browser uses **MergeSort** or **HeapSort**

Did anyone try it and can tell whether it is safe or recommend on another solution?

Answer (score 3):

The "workaround" is a terrible idea. It's inefficient (using many more calls to `Math.random()` than necessary) and, as you noted, is dangerous to use for some sorting algorithms. It's also biased (at least for the version of `sort()` in my nodeJS installation, although I can't explain why). Here's a typical result of sorting the array `[1, 2, 3]` 60,000 times and counting how many of each permutation shows up:

> [1, 2, 3]: 14,821 times
>   [1, 3, 2]: 7,637 times
>   [2, 1, 3]: 15,097 times
>   [2, 3, 1]: 7,590 times
>   [3, 1, 2]: 7,416 times
>   [3, 2, 1]: 7,439 times

For an unbiased shuffle, the six permutations should appear equally often on the average (about 10,000 times for 60,000 repetitions). In my experiments, [1, 2, 3] and [2, 1, 3] occur roughly twice as often as the other four permutations. This is consistent over many runs of the test.

You're much better sticking to the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle (described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and many other places on the web). In pseudocode, it looks like this (taken from the Wikipedia article):

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from n−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Not too complicated and definitely a better approach. Here's my JavaScript version (which could probably be cleaned up a bit):

```
function shuffleFisherYates(a) {
    var i, j, tmp;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a;
}
```

P.S. For reference, here's the code I used to test your workaround:

```
function shuffleRandomSort(a) {
    a.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
    return a;
}

function score(scores, result) {
    var index;
    if (result[0] === 1) {
        index = result[1] === 2
            ? 0  // [1, 2, 3]
            : 1; // [1, 3, 2]
    } else if (result[0] === 2) {
        index = result[1] === 1
            ? 2  // [2, 1, 3]
            : 3; // [2, 3, 1]
    } else { // result[0] === 3
        index = result[1] === 1
            ? 4  // [3, 1, 2]
            : 5; // [3, 2, 1]
    }
    scores[index]++;
}

function runTest(shuffler, n) {
    var scores = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        a;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a = [1, 2, 3];
        score(scores, shuffler(a));
    }
    console.log(scores);
}

console.log(shuffleRandomSort, runTest(60000));
```

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed some algorithms and tested them with `console.time`, you can see the results running them:

```js
var smallArray = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (x, i) => i);
var bigArray = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (x, i) => i);

function shuffle1(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = (Math.random() * currentIndex) | 0;
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
}

function shuffle2(arr) {
  return _.shuffle(arr);
}

function shuffle3(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    let j = (Math.random() * i) | 0;
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
}

// inconsistent speeds
function shuffle4(arr) {
  arr.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
}

function test(label, fn) {
  console.time(label);
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    fn();
  }
  console.timeEnd(label);
}

// time in comments based on Chrome 55

let sa1 = smallArray.slice(0);
let sa2 = smallArray.slice(0);
let sa3 = smallArray.slice(0);
let sa4 = smallArray.slice(0);
test('smallArray shuffle1', () => shuffle1(sa1)); // 0.785ms
test('smallArray shuffle2', () => shuffle2(sa2)); // 1.830ms
test('smallArray shuffle3', () => shuffle3(sa3)); // 5.540ms
test('smallArray shuffle4', () => shuffle4(sa4)); // 3.995ms

let ba1 = bigArray.slice(0);
let ba2 = bigArray.slice(0);
let ba3 = bigArray.slice(0);
let ba4 = bigArray.slice(0);
test('bigArray shuffle1', () => shuffle1(ba1)); // 14.195ms
test('bigArray shuffle2', () => shuffle2(ba2)); // 24.645ms
test('bigArray shuffle3', () => shuffle3(ba3)); // 119.425ms
test('bigArray shuffle4', () => shuffle4(ba4)); // 249.930ms
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Same Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm with ES6 is much slower :/

Comment: Yeah, both 1 and 3 are Fisher-Yates. Version 3 is probably slower because of the structured assignment (which I'm guessing isn't well optimized in most browsers). I'm surprised how poorly the lodash shuffle performs compared to a hand-coded loop. Could that be due to a lack of a warm-up loop in your test?